# Uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: -[_SwiftValue floatValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue floatValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17445bd80'

I am receiving the error above while attempting to compress video in swift.  I am quite lost as to why the reason is even a floatValue as none of the values in either of my dictionaries are floats.  This leads me to be unable to even track down the root of this issue. If anybody could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it, below are the two functions I am using to compress.

```
func compressVideo(_ inputURL: URL, outputURL: URL, handler:@escaping (_ session: SDAVAssetExportSession)-> Void)
{



    do{
        let fileLocation = URL(fileURLWithPath: inputURL.path)
        let videoData = try Data(contentsOf: fileLocation)
        print(" \n BEFORE COMPRESSION: " + mbSizeWithData(data: videoData) + "\n")
    } catch {}

    let urlAsset = AVURLAsset(url: inputURL, options: nil)

    //let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: urlAsset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
    let exportSession = SDAVAssetExportSession(asset: urlAsset)

    exportSession?.outputURL = outputURL

    exportSession?.videoSettings =
        [(AVVideoCodecKey as NSString) as String : AVVideoCodecH264 as NSString
            , AVVideoWidthKey : 1080 as Int64,
              AVVideoHeightKey : 1920 as Int64,
              AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey : [AVVideoAverageBitRateKey as NSString: 100 as Int64,
                                                                         AVVideoProfileLevelKey as NSString: AVVideoProfileLevelH264Main31, AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey as NSString: 30 as Int64]]
    exportSession?.audioSettings = [
        AVFormatIDKey : kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 2 as Int64,
        AVSampleRateKey : 44100 as Int64,
        AVEncoderBitRateKey : 128000 as Int64
    ]

    exportSession?.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4

    exportSession?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

    exportSession?.exportAsynchronously { () -> Void in

        handler(exportSession!)
    }

}


func doCompress() {
    self.url = UserDefaults.standard.url(forKey: "videoURL")
    print("\(self.url)")
    let format = DateFormatter()
    format.dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss"
    let outputURl = self.url!.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent("video\(format.string(from: Date())).mp4")
    print("\(outputURl)")
    self.compressVideo(self.url!, outputURL: outputURl, handler: { (session) in
        if session.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed
        {
            //DEBUG :
            let tempData = try? Data(contentsOf: outputURl)
            print("\n AFTER COMPRESSION: " + mbSizeWithData(data: tempData!) + "\n")

            self.url! = outputURl
            print(self.url)
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: self.url!)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.url, forKey: "videoURL")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

            print("File size after compression: \(Double(data!.count / 1048576)) mb")
            self.videoData = try? Data(contentsOf: self.url!)
            //print(self.videoData)



        }

        else if session.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.failed
        {
            print("failed")
        }
    })
}
```

}

Comment: Has the project been converted to swift 3 from a previous version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your video and audio setting value types were wrong, it looks like you switched width and height and your `AVVideoAverageBitRateKey` looks too low. Also, I'm not sure `AVVideoProfileLevelH264Main31` is supported everywhere:

```
exportSession?.videoSettings = [
    AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecH264,
    AVVideoWidthKey : NSNumber(value:1920),
    AVVideoHeightKey : NSNumber(value: 1080),
    AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey : [
        AVVideoAverageBitRateKey: NSNumber(value:100),
        // AVVideoProfileLevelKey: AVVideoProfileLevelH264Main31,
        AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey: NSNumber(value:30)
    ]
]

exportSession?.audioSettings = [
    AVFormatIDKey : NSNumber(value:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey : NSNumber(value:2),
    AVSampleRateKey : NSNumber(value:44100.0),
    AVEncoderBitRateKey : NSNumber(value:128000)
]
```

Comment: The video is vertical so the width and height should be fine correct? I will try the rest of the settings.